# How to read only the full match identified by a regular expression from the list of group matches that it returns

Tags: python, regex

I need to read all forms of numbers, currencies, numbers with units etc. with my regex from a text corpus.
I have written t he following regex that does capture all the scenarios:

```
((\d+([.,/:()-]\d+)*)([A-Za-z]*[0-9]*[/]*)*)
```

The string I am testing it on is :

```
"250 11:45 The world 11:23:45 123.45.78 123.45 123,67 567,89,89 789,90,90.09 -140 -140.67 2/4 9.8m/sec2 586.99hd/s/d"
```

The output I m getting is:

```
[('250', '250', '', ''), ('11:45', '11:45', ':45', ''), ('11:23:45', '11:23:45', ':45', ''), ('123.45.78', '123.45.78', '.78', ''), ('123.45', '123.45', '.45', ''), ('123,67', '123,67', ',67', ''), ('567,89,89', '567,89,89', ',89', ''), ('789,90,90.09', '789,90,90.09', '.09', ''), ('140', '140', '', ''), ('140.67', '140.67', '.67', ''), ('2/4', '2/4', '/4', ''), ('9.8m/sec2', '9.8', '.8', ''), ('586.99hd/s/d', '586.99', '.99', '')]
```

This implies that the regex is capturing all conditions properly.
But the output I need is the full match, i.e. the first match of the tuples returned above. I do not want any group match in the output. How do I ensure that?

I tried using anchors and and ?: lookups but somehow not working. Please help.

Comment: Use non-capturing groups by changing `(` to `(?:`

Comment: you can also access the groups of the capture via RESULT.group(INDEX)  where index is in reference to the group you are expecting

Comment: And `.group(0)` refers to the whole match. BTW, there's no need to put `()` around the whole thing, that just makes another capture group that's the same as the whole match.

Comment: Could you please post your code you used to get that output?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a capture group around the whole regexp, the first element of each tuple is the whole match. So just extract all of those.

```
[el[0] for el in result]
```

where `result` is your original output.

But you can just change your regexp to use non-capturing groups by putting `?:` at the beginning of each group.

```
(?:\d+(?:[.,/:()-]\d+)*)(?:[A-Za-z]*[0-9]*[/]*)*
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe this simple expression might work OK:

```
\d\S+
```

#### Test

```
import re

expression = r"\d\S+"

string = """
250 11:45 The world 11:23:45 123.45.78 123.45 123,67 567,89,89 789,90,90.09 -140 -140.67 2/4 9.8m/sec2 586.99hd/s/d
"""

print(re.findall(expression, string))
```

#### Output

```
['250', '11:45', '11:23:45', '123.45.78', '123.45', '123,67', '567,89,89', '789,90,90.09', '140', '140.67', '2/4', '9.8m/sec2', '586.99hd/s/d']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/BBAXQh/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/BBAXQh/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: Thanks..This helps. The only drawback of this will be when a sentence from which I need t o extract numerical data ends with a number. In that case the punctuation my come as a part of the number